# Hide parent div if startAddress or endAddress matches any of the waypoints

Tags: jquery

I am currently iterating through all of my divs to check if their waypoint attribute is equal to the one set in the as `startAddress` and `destinationAddress`.

If there is no match out of all the waypoint items in the div, I want to hide the parent container (`rideshare-item`) and carry on. But if there is a match, I do not want to hide it.

How do I go about doing this? I am currently iterating through all the divs but I am not sure how to hide and unhide things.

**JavaScript**

```
$('body').on('click', '#go-button', function(event){
    // Collect values
    var startAddress = $('.start-address').val();
    var destinationAddress = $('.destination-address').val();
    // Only show matching pickup address and waypoint
    $('.rideshare-item').show();
    $('.rideshare-item .rideshare-detail .waypoint').each(function(a,b){
        var waypoint = $(b).data('waypoint');
        if((waypoint == startAddress) || (waypoint == destinationAddress)){
            // do not hide div element
        }
        else if($((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress)) 
                && a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length-1) {
            // hide div element 
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row rideshare-item">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default rideshare-detail" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel-body"> <strong>Waypoints</strong>
                <br>
                <br> <span style="color:#449D44">Start</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Hall">Hall</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Apartments">Apartments</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Train Station">Train Station</span>
                <br> <span style="color:#c12e2a">Stop</span>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row rideshare-item">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default rideshare-detail" style="display: none;">
            <div class="panel-body"> <strong>Waypoints</strong>
                <br>
                <br> <span style="color:#449D44">Start</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Lab">Lab</span>
                <br> <span class="waypoint" data-waypoint="Park">Park</span>
                <br> <span style="color:#c12e2a">Stop</span>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest('.rideshare-item')` to get the parent element with `rideshare-item` class

```
 $('.rideshare-item .rideshare-detail .waypoint').each(function(a,b){
    var waypoint = $(b).data('waypoint');
    if((waypoint == startAddress) || (waypoint == destinationAddress)){
        // do not hide div element
    }
    else if($((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress)) 
            && a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length-1) {

            $(this).closest('.rideshare-item').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to hide the correct parent element

Comment: @methuselah you are sure it executes it right? Can you put a `alert` or `console.log` to make sure?

Comment: I've added `alert (waypoint);` after `var waypoint = $(b).data('waypoint');`, which tells me that it is looping through each waypoint element successfully. Beyond this I am not sure. I have however managed to get it working at http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/5/, but it doesn't seem to be working once I translate it into another instance of my code (i.e. the above example).

Comment: @methuselah for example what instance? there must be something for that one?

Comment: @methuselah do you have `console.log` working fine for this instance?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of hiding using jQuery:

```
$('element').hide();
$('element').fadeOut();
$('element').slideToggle();
$('element').css('display', 'none');
$('element').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

To: other users -

if there are other ways, please update my answer with them.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e3kg160g/7/ you forgot the missing brace for your `.click` event